# jQuery prev() and next()

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery. I have HTML code which looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>123</li>
    <li id="hello">456</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>789</li>
</ul>
```

I want, with jQuery, to get the li element after #hello (the 789 element). I tried with `$('#hello').next()`, it does not work.

How do I do?

Comment: next() works for siblings, but the element you're trying to get to is up a level. If you just want that particular list item, you'll have to get the parent unordered list, then use next(), and then get the child list item, but it's pretty inefficient and I wouldn't do that if you want to apply the code elsewhere.

Comment: How would you define `next` in the context of a tree which is the DOM. I ask because depending on the document structure, the answer may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#hello').parent().next().children();
```

- the [`parent()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method to go up to the `<ul>` element
- the [`next()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method to go to the next `<ul>` element
- the [`children()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method to get the nested `<li>` element

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
$('#hello').parent().next().children().eq(0)
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/ might be useful